# Add forsaken sites to the now-roomier footer

Tags: bug, status-completed, footer

Now that the sites sections in the footer are bigger, there should be room to add previously-omitted sites like [Software Recommendations](//softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) and [Network Engineering](//networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) under the technology section.

Calling this a bug because it looks like an oversight; ExpressionEngine is included but SR and NE are both larger sites by many measures.

Comment: The "more" on categories like "Life / Arts" and  "Science" now seem entirely redundant as well, given the oodles of empty space (and "Culture/ Recreation", to an extent).

Comment: Yes, there are now 5 columns that can list of 7 sites, so that leaves room for 34 sites + a more() link if there are more than 35 sites. I agree and see no reason not to use that space.

Comment: [blender.se], which is even larger, is also omitted.

Comment: @Matt The more link can still get you to the beta sites under those categories. We don't plan to ever list those in the footer of main sites, regardless of how much space there is.

Comment: Absolutely @animuson, being listed on the footer has always been considered a graduation perk, I don't see a reason to change that. For the already graduated sites, though, this is a chance to follow through on that promise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That was always the intention, though the missing sites were missing as an oversight.

We put a process in place to ensure sites do show up more promptly.

You will notice that the footer on other Stack Exchange sites includes those sites now as well.

There are still a few missing ones, where we don't have space for the category in the footers.

We do intend on fixing that going forward, but need to figure out what that looks like. Could be recategorising sites, design work, combination of both or something entirely different. Time will tell.